# Parse JSON API from Dictionary to ObservableCollection for ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Parse an API endpoint with errors.

> This is the raw JSON returning from API

```
{"posts":{"29.11.2018":[{"title":"xxx","image_url":null,"message":"xxxx","time":"08:30 AM"}]}
```

> This is my RootObject

```
    public class Notification
    {
        [JsonProperty("posts")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<Post>> posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image_url")]
        public Uri imageUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string time { get; set; }
    }
```

> My service class

```
var notification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Notification>>(apiContent); //Deserialize the JSON data
var _schoolNotification = new ObservableCollection<Post>(notification.Keys);
NotificationListView.ItemsSource = _schoolNotification;
```

> My Edited XAML

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource ListViewTitle}" Text="{Binding title}" />
   <Label Text="{Binding message}" TextColor="{DynamicResource ListViewDateColor}" />
</StackLayout>
```

The issue i am facing is, i cant parse this Dictionary to a ObservableColection to be used by Xamarin.Forms.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the specific problem - deserializing the json or creating the observablecollection?  Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since it doesnt reply to the problem itself. I wait for you to clarify what error are you getting.

Comment: The error i am getting with my current implementation is: Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Notification>.KeyCollection to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Post> @BrunoCaceiro

Comment: yes look at my answer i have already anticipated it.

Comment: Have you checked if var notification is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the previews answer was right but need casting so try this

```
//Deserialize the JSON data

  var notification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(apiContent); 

    List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
      if (notification?.posts != null){
        foreach(var item in notification.posts.Values){
           posts.AddRange(item);
         }
       }
    var _schoolNotification = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
```

Comment: With this implementation above the `posts.AddRange(item.posts);` throws a conversion error

Comment: my bad i did not see the dicationary in Notification class, sorry. i did fix the code have a look.

Comment: I ran with the changes and the app crashes and produces a System.NullReferenceException

Comment: haha yes if posts is null you will get error. ok have fixed it now. test it and see

Comment: Well it didnt crash but but it didnt return any data and there are data coming from the API. Question why did we have to create a new instance of Post `List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();`

Comment: new ObservableCollection must have a value and also you cant do AddRang in null. if you did not get data that means that JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is returning null, so the problem is there. Debug the code and se whats wrong with the values. the code i wrote fixes your problem but now you have another one. check that notification containes a value. and please mark this as answer later on when u find the other problem

Comment: Well now i see the problem your json string is returning Notification and your are trying to convert it to dictionary, will rewrite the whole code for you just a moment. try the new code now it should work

Comment: item in `item.posts.Values` does not exist in the current context

Comment: my bad its notification.posts.Values.

Comment: Okay this seems to work with one error. On my XAML page the result does not show up. Does this change how i have the bindings in the XAML?

Comment: no it dose not. maybe a design that hade the values. i really dont know. open another thread and post the whole XAML code there and lets se.

Comment: I updated the XAML that was attached to the problem.

Comment: where is the NotificationListView

Comment: That piece of XAML is extracted from the NotificationListView which is a ViewCell with a stacklayout in it. 

Also i have `NotificationListView.ItemsSource = _schoolNotification;` in the code behind below the solution you gave

Comment: Same here, looking at the API response for multiple items i realize that each item in the API is grouped by date eg) {"posts":{"29.11.2018":[{"title":"xxx","image_url":null,"message":"xxxx","time":"08:30 AM"},"17.11.2018":{"title":"xxx","image_url":null,"message":"xxxx","time":"08:30 AM"}]}

Comment: yes if its a list of Notification but as your json start with '{' i dont think that its a list of Notification, so no it should not effect the parsing.

Comment: The only thing that shows up after it parses is : Appname.models.Post

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running your JSON response through jsonutils.com and using that generated class as the model in the deserialization step. It’s usually fool proof and removes the potential human error when trying to manually define the classes.